# Iframes & Div alignment in IE9..Revised July 4th

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am attempting to utilize `iframe`s with div elements while using a JavaScript function with

```
document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML = '<iframe frameborder=0 align=left valign=top width=650 height=500 scrolling=no src=\''+pageload+'\'></iframe>';
```

I have three `div`s atop each other. In Firefox & Chrome the div elements move downwards as expected. However, while the function loads all links fine initially, I load a div with a graphic which I enlarged to cover the iframe in MSIE as it originally appeared to small and it then appeared fine. However, after loading a couple of divs the graphic exploded in size beneath the other divs. The pages aren't positioned appropriately in the divs afterwards and CSS formatting, float etc has no effect...Any ideas?

I have the html doc type to "Quirks Mode". Any ideas why all goes away in MSIE??

Comment: You are far more likely to receive help if you can present a minimal code example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I have edited your question, although I am still struggling to understand. As @paddy commented, you MUST include source code - that will also help to explain your question where your choice of words cannot. Also, consider making a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: You should never be in quirks mode. That will be the problem.

Comment: Greetings...I appreciate your assistance I am using the below that builds the iframe from a javascript function all works fine, just all goes bad in MSIE

Comment: document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML = '<iframe frameborder=0 align=left valign=top width=650 height=500 scrolling=no src=\''+pageload+'\'></iframe>';

Comment: While everything loads, the pages aren't positioned appropriately and CSS formatting, float etc has no effect...Originally a graphic I enlarged to cover the iframe in MSIE as it originally appeared to small..the initial load it appears great.. after another load of a DIV the graphic explodes in size and over runs the site as the iframe or div isn't fixed in size??..any ideass